# (Xcode 11.2.1) Cannot find Thread Sanitizer runtime support library (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, swift5, thread-sanitizer

With Xcode 11.2.1 created a single View project for iOS and enabled the Thread Sanitizer in Scheme. Note: Running the app on Simulator **iPhone Xr 13.2.2**

Once run the project, getting below error:

**The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified ("null").**

```
Details

The request to open "kumar.helloworld" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) 
for reason: Unspecified ("null").
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = RequestDenied;
    FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = 0x9e5a;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (null)
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: (null)
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = Unspecified;
}
```

When set the executable as **Ask on Launch** getting the below error:

**Cannot find Thread Sanitizer runtime support library. Please specify it manually by setting DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES environment variable.**

If disabled the **Thread Sanitizer**, then app is launching properly in the simulator.

Any help in this case will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Already tried **Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings ...** on simulator, deleted the content in derived data folder, restarted Xcode and simulator but nothing helped.

Comment: @jean-françois-fabre, do you have any working solution for this problem ? May I know why the answer was deleted ?